# How severe is my laptop liquid damaged?

Tags: laptop-repair, repair

Okay guys so I was cleaning my laptop with 70% medicinal alcohol, and I accidently spilt I'd say 1-2 teaspoon on the keyboard. I then unplugged it immeadiately and shut it down. Without any further thinking, I thought because only a little dropped on the keyboard, and thought none went in, I continued to use the laptop whilst charging. I used it for about 1-2 hours and it was working fine. It was stupid to do so, as I had some important uni assignment to  continue on. I didn't really think much of the spillage whilst using it.

I turned on the laptop the next day to find out the keys are randomly pressing, with some keys not working. I then realised, "Gosh, what a terrible mistake last night was!" I know its from the spillage. The laptop turns on fine, boots into windows, just trouble with the keyboard. Now my question is, how severe is the  damage? Is it only the keyboard or is there high chances the motherboard is hit aswell? This is an Asus S15 Vivobook, I've had it for 2-3 months now.
Thank you

Comment: theres no way to tell, until you replace the keyboard, and even then, only if you can tell the difference between mostly working and completely working.

Comment: There's a good lesson on what not to do with a spill, on the Ask Different site - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219053/no-sound-speakers-jack-microphones-dead-after-spilling-water

Comment: Replace the keyboard and go from there.

Comment: Do you reckon the motherboard is alright? I am worried the motherboard is affected. But I am certain the keyboard has some layer before it reaches the motherboard.

Comment: @user478905 The fact your keyboard is malfunctioning is proof enough the liquid reached the motherboard. Alcohol is thinner than water and your isopropyl mix likely permeated the moboard after damaging your keyboard. You're lucky for the moment if your system boots and functions, but plan on replacing it at an undetermined future date sooner than later.

Answer (score 1):

Start planning to replace your Asus at an undetermined future date.

I own and service Thinkpads, systems literally [designed and advertised to survive liquid spills](https://www3.lenovo.com/hk/en/thisisthinkpad/innovation/spill-resistant-keyboard-with-a-thinkpad-an-accidental-spill-is-a-distraction-not-a-disaster/) and the caveats are they'll immediately survive a spill, long enough to migrate off TPM keys, long enough to remove hard drives.

But they've always eventually declined with vexing errors, random reboots, screen flickering before totally dying.

This image, like many, is from Lenovo's own site and part of their legendary spill resistance by using internal canals meant to channel liquid through isolated drain ports and cellophane encased keyboards and they still eventually die after getting soaked.
[image]
Asus was never in danger of being known for spill resistance, consider yourself lucky for the moment but don't start planning to bequeath that laptop to your grandchildren.

Wishful thinking won't alter your current reality.